# Scala for-comprehension for orElse instead of flatMap

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I'm quite familiar with `for` comprehension and `flatMap` on Options.

So I know you can do something like

```
val a: Option[_] = for {
  foo <- Some(x)
  bar <- Some(y)
  baz <- Some(z)
} yield baz
```

which gives me `Some(z)` if nothing in the for comprehension is `None`, since it is doing a `flatMap` on each statement.

But actually I'm looking for something the other way round. I would like to traverse to `for` comprehension, as long everything is `None`, like a `orElse` in a `for` comprehension.

for example:

```
val b: Option[_] = for {
    foo <- None
    bar <- Some(x)
    baz <- None
} yield *return the one with some*
```

Is there anything like this, or what's the best approach for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reduce` will not short circuit when it finds a `Some` (i.e. a thousand element list will do a thousand comparisons even if the first element is a `Some`). `find(_.isDefined)` + `flatten` will stop and return the first `Some` it finds. The following will only do 2 comparisons (rather than 5).

```
val xs: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, Some(1), None, Some(2), None, Some(3))
xs.find(_.isDefined).flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

A for-comprehension doesn't really make sense in your scenario.  You're better off just putting the items in a collection and pulling out a non-None.

Maybe something like this?

```
val xs: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, Some(1), None)
xs.reduce(_ orElse _) // Some(1)

val ys: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, None)
ys.reduce(_ orElse _) // None
```

Comment: thank you! I wasn't thinking of that way, but totally makes sense ;)